# Refactoring: removal of duplication in constructor

Tags: java, refactoring

I seem to be lacking enough coffee to make me see the following problem clearly.

Imagine I have a class with two constructors and several fields. One constructor is a no-arg constructor and one field depends on another. The other constructor takes an injected value for one of its fields. Example:

```
public class Practice {
    private final int n;
    private final char c;
    private final Map<String, String> m;
    private final Set<String> s;

    public Practice() {
        this.n = 0;
        this.c = 'a';
        this.m = new HashMap<>();
        this.s = m.keySet();
    }
    
    public Practice(Set<String> s) {
        this.n = 0;
        this.c = 'a';
        this.m = new HashMap<>();
        this.s = s;
    }
}
```

**My question: how do I remove the duplication of code between the two constructors?**

First failed attempt:

```
public Practice() {
    this(new HashMap<>(), new HashMap<>().keySet());
}

public Practice(Set<String> s) {
    this(new HashMap<>(), s);
}

private Practice(int n, char c, Map<String, String> m, Set<String> s) {
    this.n = 0;
    this.c = 'a';
    this.m = m;
    this.s = s;
}
```

Of course, this fails because the no-args constructor creates two separate Maps instead of one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In cases where one argument depends on another argument you can solve the problem by adding an additional constructor. In this case `private Practice(Map<String,String> map)`

```
public Practice() {
    this(new HashMap<>());
}

public Practice(Set<String> s) {
    this(new HashMap<>(), s);
}

private Practice(Map<String,String> map) {
    this(map, map.keySet());
}

private Practice(Map<String,String> map, Set<String> s) {
    this.n = 0;
    this.c = 'a';
    this.m = map;
    this.s = s;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can just initialize variables as you define them as members. In your constructor you can stick to initializing strictly those variables that can hold a different value after initialization.

Also note: Since `n` and `c` are primitives they are suitable candidates to be `static`, since they are also tagged `final`. This does not hold true for `m`.

```
public class Practice {
    private static final int n = 0;
    private static final char c = 'a';
    private final Map<String, String> m = new HashMap<>();
    private final Set<String> s;

    public Practice() {
        this.s = m.keySet();
    }
    
    public Practice(Set<String> s) {
        this.s = s;
    }
}
```

Lastly - it is not necessary to kill each and any duplication of code. The rules on this vary, though I usually follow the rule-of-three or when the duplicated chunks are large.

Answer (score 1):

For the initial version, you could pass a `null` from the default constructor and then check for `null` when setting `s`:

```java
public class Practice {
    private final int n;
    private final char c;
    private final Map<String, String> m;
    private final Set<String> s;

    public Practice() {
        this(null);
    }
    
    public Practice(Set<String> s) {
        this.n = 0;
        this.c = 'a';
        this.m = new HashMap<>();
        this.s = null == s ? m.keySet() : s;
    }
}
```

Similarly, the version with 3 constructors can be updated:

```java
public Practice() {
    this(null);
}

public Practice(Set<String> s) {
    this(0, 'a', new HashMap<>(), s); // as all args constructor is private
}

private Practice(int n, char c, Map<String, String> m, Set<String> s) {
    this.n = n;
    this.c = c;
    this.m = m;
    this.s = null == s ? m.keySet() : s;
}
```

Comment: Just a remark: `null == s` is typically a C/C++ style to prevent _conditions accidently assigning_ like `s = null ? ...`. In java this cannot happen by language design.

Comment: @JoopEggen, if `s` were of type `Boolean`, even language design could not have helped against a NPE  `Boolean ok = true; System.out.println((ok = null) ? "OK": "Bad");` :)  I caught this habit in the middle of the 90-s, it's like a safety measure to use _literals_ on the _left_ and _Lvalues_ on the _right_ side of `==` comparison, because literals cannot be assigned.

Comment: [Yoda conditions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yoda_conditions) these are called.

Comment: Yes with me it is a habit from permissive C/C++ fimes. It is an unnatural formulation ("x equals three" versus "three equals x") so when using java I generally refrain from it. I wonder whether java code style checkers tend to your style.

Comment: @k314159 enjoyed. Above yoda conditions not harmful at all seems to be